# DBISAM - Error 8708 - Version 2.03

Tags: sql, dbisam

I am trying to update the field CNAME and using it on a Where clause:

```
update SGT000 set CName='STA2'where CName='STA23'
```

The DBISAM raises a exception 8708 (Record has been changed or deleted by another user in table 'SGT000.DAT')
I am using version 2.03

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. It is a bug in 2.03 version.

http://www.elevatesoft.com/incident?action=viewrep&category=dbisam&release=2.03&incident=604